# WSO2 APIManager: How can I increase the expires_in time in Access Token

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We want to try to increase the lifetime of our OAuthAccessTokens (generated by a WSO2 Identity server client_credentials as Grant Type). We tried to do it in the Postman by setting the 'validity_period', by changing the time settings in the service provider but nothing changed the validity period of the token. It stays always at 3600 seconds. Can anyone give us a hint about which attributes to change the expiration time of the OAuthAccessTokens?

Comment: Did you try editing the service provider created in IS?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using client_credentials grant type you should update the `Application Access Token Expiry Time` in Service Provider configurations.